# scala regex replaceAllIn can't replace when replace string looks like a regex?

Tags: regex, scala

I've been happily running a Regex `replaceAllIn` for quite a while but ran into a problem when the `replacement` string had something that looked like a regex in it.  The following illustrates the problem (Scala 2.9.1-1).  Note that the real problem space is much more complex, so the idea of using a simpler solution isn't really tenable (just to preempt the inevitable "Why don't you try ..." :D)

```
val data = "val re = \"\"\"^[^/]*://[^/]*/[^/]*$\"\"\".r"
val source = """here
LATEX_THING{abc}
there"""
val re = "LATEX_THING\\{abc\\}".r
println(re.replaceAllIn(source, data))
```

This presents with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
```

If I change `data` from what it was to something simple like:

```
val data = "This will work"
```

Then everything's fine.

It looks like `replaceAllIn` is somehow looking in the second string and using it as another RE to reference what was remembered from the first RE... but the docs say nothing about this.

What am I missing?

**edit**: Ok, so after looking at the `java.util.regex.Matcher` class, it would seem that the intended fix is:

```
re.replaceAllIn(source, java.util.regex.Matcher.quoteReplacement(data))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` in your replacement string:

```
val data = "val re = \"\"\"^[^/]*://[^/]*/[^/]*\\$\"\"\".r"
```

Otherwise it's interpreted as the beginning of a group reference (which would only be valid if the `$` were followed by one or more digits). See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for `java.util.regex.Matcher` for more detail:

> The replacement string may contain references to subsequences captured
>   during the previous match: Each occurrence of `$g` will be replaced by
>   the result of evaluating `group(g)`... A dollar sign (`$`) may be
>   included as a literal in the replacement string by preceding it with a
>   backslash (`\$`).

Update to address your comment and edit above: Yes, you can use `Matcher.quoteReplacement` if you're not working with string literals (or if you are, I guess, but escaping the `$` seems easier in that case), and there's at least [a chance](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/139) that `quoteReplacement` will be available as a method on `scala.util.matching.Regex` in the future.

Comment: Thank you sir.  It didn't occur to me to head to the Java docs... that's what I get for never being a real Java coder, I guess.  The `data` in question actually comes from a Scala source file.  I guess the rule of thumb is, unless you know exactly what you've got, preprocess it first by substituting the `$` for `\$` and then process it the way you want.

Comment: As of Scala 2.12.6 `quoteReplacement` is now available in `scala.util.matching.Regex` https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/util/matching/Regex$.html#quoteReplacement(text:String):String