# String replacement issue with `replaceAllIn` method in Scala

Tags: string, scala, templates, replace

I have this template formatting code in Scala from [Better String formatting in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051308/better-string-formatting-in-scala)

```
  def getTemplateString(template:String, replacement:Map[String, String]) = {
    replacement.foldLeft(template)((s:String, x:(String,String)) => ( "#\\{" + x._1 + "\\}" ).r.replaceAllIn( s, x._2 ))
  }
```

The issue is that with a mapped value with '$' character, I get `Illegal group reference java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference` error.

```
val template = "#{a}"
val map = Map[String, String]("a" -> "$bp")
val res = getTemplateString(template, map)
println(res)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658701/scala-regex-replaceallin-cant-replace-when-replace-string-looks-like-a-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the $ symbol:

```
val map = Map[String, String]("a" -> "\\$bp")
```